# Python bitarray reverse complement

Tags: python, bitarray

I am using Python's `bitarray module` to convert a DNA sequence, that is written in a binary file, to its reverse complement.  Each nucleotide is represented by two bits in the following format: 
`A - 00, C - 01, G - 10, T - 11`.

For example, the reverse complement of 
`AGCTACGG (00 10 01 11 00 01 10 10)` would be `CCGTAGCT (01 01 10 11 00 10 01 11)`.
This sequence takes up exactly *16 bits (2 bytes)*, but a sequence of length *9* would take *18 bits* and it is padded to take up *24* bits (*3* bytes).

At the moment I use a for cycle for the conversion, but this solution is dreadfully slow.

```
def reverse_complement( my_bitarray, seq_length ):

    for i in range(0, 2 * seq_length - 1, 2):

        if my_bitarray[i] == my_bitarray[i + 1]:

            if my_bitarray[i] == 0:
                my_bitarray[i], my_bitarray[i + 1] = 1, 1

            else:
                my_bitarray[i], my_bitarray[i + 1] = 0, 0

    #padding if the bitarray is not a multiple of 8 bits in length
    if seq_length / 4 != int():
        my_bitarray.reverse()
        my_bitarray.fill()
        my_bitarray.reverse()

    return my_bitarray

a = bitarray()
a.frombytes(seq[::-1])
b = a[int(seq_start)::] # seq without padding
b.reverse()

reverse_complement(b, seq_length)
```

Any tips on how to make this process faster?

Comment: Does that code really do what you describe in the text?

Comment: @skyking I'm sorry, I left a part out that is out of this function, will edit my post. Thank you for the critical thinking!

Comment: Have you tried using a LUT on the byte representation of the sequence? I haven't tried it but it might perform better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't give the answer you indicated.

Here is code that gives the correct answer. Perhaps it will also be fast enough:

```
def reverse_complement(my_bitarray):
    # First reverse by twos
    my_bitarray = zip(my_bitarray[0::2], my_bitarray[1::2])
    my_bitarray = reversed(list(my_bitarray))
    my_bitarray = (i for t in my_bitarray for i in t)
    my_bitarray = bitarray(my_bitarray)

    # Then complement
    my_bitarray.invert()
    return my_bitarray
```

Note that you don't have to worry about the padding. `bitarray.bitarray()` manages all of that for you.

Comment: I get an error message: TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Comment: I've updated the answer to be compatible with either Python3 or Python2.

Comment: Thanks! It is working, but i do need to worry about padding, if my initial bitarray has padding in the beginning I need to exclude it from the real "sequence" that gets reverse complemented.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing the [boltons](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boltons) package from PyPI, you can do the following:

```
from itertools import chain

from bitarray import bitarray
from boltons.iterutils import pairwise

original = bitarray('0010011100011010')
complement = ~original
reverse_complement = bitarray(chain.from_iterable(reversed(pairwise(complement))))
assert reverse_complement == bitarray('0101101100100111')
```

## **Update**:

As of [boltons v16.2.0](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1620), `pairwise` does something else, so the answer should be changed to use `chunked`:

```
from boltons.iterutils import chunked
reverse_complement = bitarray(chain.from_iterable(reversed(chunked(complement, 2))))
```